# Visual Basic - Simple Web Scraper

Tags: excel, vba

Novice question incoming; I am following a web series on YouTube on how to screen scrap information off a web page. The goal is to be able to use this on an internal company application I have which simply displays a blank web page with text values. However after two days I still can't figure out why I can't make a simple function call work in VB. Everything I've done so far continues to throw a compile error when I click the button, 'Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()', on my form.

Here is the code for the button:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
'FirstMacro

    Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    objIE.Top = 0
    objIE.Left = 0
    objIE.Width = 800
    objIE.Height = 600
    objIE.AddressBar = 0
    objIE.StatusBar = 0
    objIE.Toolbar = 0
    objIE.Visible = True 'We will see the window navigation'

    objIE.Navigate ("http://www.google.com")
    TextBox4.Text objIE.Document.body.innerHTML 
End Sub
```

Here is the code for the class:

```
Public Function FirstMacro()
'the_start:

    Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    objIE.Top = 0
    objIE.Left = 0
    objIE.Width = 800
    objIE.Height = 600
    objIE.AddressBar = 0
    objIE.StatusBar = 0
    objIE.Toolbar = 0
    objIE.Visible = True 'We will see the window navigation'

    'MsgBox.Err.Number

    'On Error Resume Next
       'MsgBox.objIE.Document.body.innerHTML
        'If Err.Number > 0 Then
            'objIE.Quit
            'Set objIE = Nothing
            'GoTo the_start:
        'End If
    
    objIE.Navigate ("http://www.google.com")

    'Do
        'DoEvents
    'Loop Until objIE.ReadyState = 4

    TextBox4.Text objIE.Document.body.innerHTML
End Function
```

And this is the series I'm following: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Blls6GrCBCY&index=12&list=PL6OYc4rwKjcOu3UL7LYpvO_S2waYO-hVU

Thanks for helping the noob.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably try something like this.

```
Sub DumpData()

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True

URL = "http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=sbux&ql=1"

'Wait for site to fully load
IE.Navigate2 URL
Do While IE.Busy = True
   DoEvents
Loop

RowCount = 1

With Sheets("Sheet1")
   .Cells.ClearContents
   RowCount = 1
   For Each itm In IE.document.all
      .Range("A" & RowCount) = itm.tagname
      .Range("B" & RowCount) = itm.ID
      .Range("C" & RowCount) = itm.classname
      .Range("D" & RowCount) = Left(itm.innertext, 1024)

      RowCount = RowCount + 1
   Next itm
End With
End Sub
```

Then, you should have a better idea of what you are dealing with at each URL.